# How to import data with class interval from excel to R

Tags: r

I have data from excel which should be a group data(the one I higlight in the picture), the problem is, when i import it to R, it won't consider those data as grouped, how can i fix the problem?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LjVl.png]

Comment: Have you tried with the `readxl` package?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "grouped"? Give an example of what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the image you provide. They are 3 separated columns, so when you import the excel file to Rstudio. It will treat them as 3 different columns. However, if you want to unite 3 columns into 1. There are also solutions for that.

Comment: I want to let it be separated like that, so when i export it to R, for example in the first collumn, it won't consider " 2-4 hours" as a range data, but as a the name of data